# How can I access a variable in a web worker?

Tags: javascript

```
function set_worker(){

        demo_worker = new Worker("worker.js");

        demo_worker.onmessage = function(event){
            demo_A = event.data;
            console.log(demo_A); // success. I get some result
        }

    }
    set_worker();
    console.log(demo_A); //undefined. i get undefined..
```

I want to access "demo_A". Why is `demo_A` `undefined`? Is there a way to access demo_A?

Comment: You need to show more information. When is `console.log(demo_A)` called in relation to `set_worker()`? You should probably be looking to trigger some event inside your `onmessage` from the web worker, so that any listeners know there has been a change

Comment: You never declared `demo_A`... and you wonder why it is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Make `demo_A` global**.

You have defined the variable in `demo_worker.onmessage()` function.
    its context will remain inside function only.Make it global.

**2. Trigger some function when you receive the message.**

`demo_A` is updated when message received so if you print `demo_A` before message is received then it may be `undefined` or may have some old value.

```
var demo_A ;//make it global
somefunction function(){//triggered when msg recieved 
  console.log(demo_A); 
  //do other stuff
}
function set_worker(){

        demo_worker = new Worker("worker.js");

        demo_worker.onmessage = function(event){
            demo_A = event.data;
             console.log(demo_A);
            somefunction(); // trigger some function 
        }

    }
    set_worker();
```

Comment: thank you. I don't know how do i say... actually i want to use 'demo_A' in main thread. anyway thank you very much it helps me.

Comment: @user3886365 You're welcome! If my answer suited your needs, don't forget to accept it (same for the other questions you asked :)
 http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/186921